# How to enable trust between two KDC's with same kerberos realm and same domain names?

Tags: security, kerberos

I have two linux clusters in different DC's with same domain name and same realm but the KDC's are different. How can i enable trust between these two KDC's ??

Answer (score 0):

Realm names must be unique; if multiple KDCs have different realms with the same name, the client will not be able to distinguish them and won't know which KDC it needs to get a ticket from – it will think both KDCs belong to the same realm and won't realize there is a trust.

(Also, Kerberos trust relationships are built using principals `krbtgt/<SrcRealm>@<DstRealm>`. But you can't do that when realm names are the same, because that principal name is already taken by the regular TGS principal.)

You *can* have multiple KDCs for the *same* realm, but their data must be fully replicated between each other (same krbtgt, same all other principals) – no trust needed in that case. You can use `kprop` for replication or use a shared LDAP backend. However, if the realms need to have different data, then they must have different names as well.

Comment: When I say "data must be fully replicated", it is technically possible to transplant just a single server's principal+keys from one KDC to another, and then you'll be able to log in to it like it's local to both KDCs (again no trust needed). But doing so on a per-principal basis is honestly a bit silly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We initially had a different realm but had some issue hard to debug and when the realm was made same as the domain name, it worked ! hard to understand why it was not working when realm and domain names were different which should ideally work!

Comment: Kerberos realm and DNS domain names can be different, you just need `[domain_realm]` mappings in krb5.conf – ideally on all clients _and_ KDCs. Of course, if one DNS domain maps to two Kerberos realms, that's always going to be a bit weird...